# Tika slower in my Java app than in TikaJAXRS

Tags: java, performance, apache-tika

I'm trying to make use of Tika from a C# project that needs to extract text from a large volume of files.

I started with a simple proof of concept that made use of TikaJAXRS, reading the content of the files and making a HTTP PUT request with the file content to the TikaJAXRS server at `http://localhost:9998/tika`. This works reasonably well, but it struck me that the overhead of streaming content through HTTP must be slowing things down.

So I decided to write a Java implementation to see how the performance would compare once HTTP is removed from the equation. What I've found is unexpected. It performs *much* slower, taking roughly twice as long to parse 65 files of various types totaling 16MB. 1200ms for the TikaJAXRS HTTP scenario, 2400ms for the Java app.

Both the TikaJAXRS server and the Tika libraries I'm using are version 1.7. My Java code listing is below. What am I missing, why is my Java app so much slower?

```
import org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;

public class TikaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // I'm not interested in what log4j has to say...
        org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure(new NullAppender());

        File folder = new File("C:\\LMDevelopment");

        StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
        timer.start();

        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(folder, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
        Tika tikaClient = new Tika();
        try {
            tikaClient.parseToString(files.iterator().next());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TikaException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Time to warm up: " + timer.getTime() + "ms");

        timer.reset();
        timer.start();
        for (File f : files)
        {
            try {
                tikaClient.parseToString(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TikaException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        timer.stop();
        System.out.println("Time to parse all files: " + timer.getTime() + "ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but could it be that TikaJAXRS is performed asynchronous and your Java app is parsing all files sequentially?

Comment: Both are synchronous and single-threaded. My TikaJAXRS client will not send another parsing request until a full response is received for the previous file.